# setRadius: not a number, Google Maps V3 in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-5, geometry

I'm trying to show a map with a marker and a circle in a MVC 5 project.
The map shows with the marker but on the circle method a get the error setRadius: not a number.

Here the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        initialize();
    });
    function initialize() {

        var myLat = '@Model.Lat'.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '');
        var myLong = '@Model.Lon'.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '');

        var rad = '@Model.Acc'.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '');

        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong); // LatLng of center point of circle

        var mapOptions = {
            center: center,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          mapOptions);
        // create a marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center,
            map: map,
            title: 'My Place'
        });

        var options = {
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: '#3366FF',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            map: map,
            center: center,
            radius: rad
        };

        circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
    }
</script>

<br />
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:480px;">
</div>
```

I displayed the variable rad with an alert and the value is 10.5, if I set manually the option radius to 10.5 it works.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the issue.
I replaced

```
radius: rad
```

With

```
radius: parseFloat(rad)
```

Hope helps also someone else.

Comment: Thank god for you man! I knew my code was perfect except for this one little modification! Why is `parseFloat` so essential?

Comment: @WebDevDanno the rad variable was defined as a string, so parseFloat converts it into a number.